# Flask Application on Azure App Service throwing "400 Bad Request" error

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I have deployed a simple `Flask app` on `Azure App Service` using Azure DevOps Build and Release pipeline. Flask app just takes user input and returns it back, on local deployment & testing its running without any issue, I can see the expected output but when the app is deployed on the App service and request is sent from either Postman or Python then I am getting the below error.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

Below are relevant data

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/chat', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def chat():
   data = request.json
   return jsonify(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

**send_request.py**

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://<app>.azurewebsites.net/chat"

payload = json.dumps({
  "name": "Atinesh Singh"
})
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

**Azure DevOps Release pipeline configuration**
[image]

**App Service Access Restrictions settings**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed I had to update the endpoint url from `http://<app>.azurewebsites.net/chat` to `https://<app>.azurewebsites.net/chat`